# Change x-tick labels - matplotlib, python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

In my plot i want to enlarge a certain area. Unfortunately this changes the x-tick labels in a unpleasant way, as u can see in the following picture:

[image]

Instead of this i want the labeling 1.2965, 1.2967, 1.297.

I tried to change the font.size but the problems still remains.